# Reading formatted data into R

Tags: r

I am trying to use `stdin` to read data into R. I want to read data in the following format:

```
5       #rows matrix A
7       #cols matrix A
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 10 11 12 13
14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27
28 29 30 31 32 33 34
3       #rows matrix B
4       #cols matrix B
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 10 11
100     #param1
-7      #param2
9       #param3
```

An example of how I would like to read the data is best exemplified by the following c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* readMatrix(int rows, int cols) {
    int* matrix = (int*) malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows*cols; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &matrix[i]);
    }
    return matrix;
}

int main() {
    int a_rows, a_cols; 
    int b_rows, b_cols;
    int *a, *b;
    int param1, param2, param3;

    scanf("%d %d", &a_rows, &a_cols);
    a = readMatrix(a_rows, a_cols);

    scanf("%d %d", &b_rows, &b_cols);
    b = readMatrix(b_rows, b_cols);

    scanf("%d %d %d", &param1, &param2, &param3);

    return 0;
}
```

My "equivalent" R code is something like this:

```
a_rows <- scan(file="stdin", what=integer(0), n=1);
a_cols <- scan(file="stdin", what=integer(0), n=1);
A <- matrix(scan(file="stdin", n = a_rows*a_cols), a_rows, a_cols, byrow = TRUE)

b_rows <- scan(file="stdin", what=integer(0), n=1);
b_cols <- scan(file="stdin", what=integer(0), n=1);
B <- matrix(scan(file="stdin", n = b_rows*b_cols), b_rows, b_cols, byrow = TRUE)

param1 <- scan(file="stdin", what=integer(0), n=1);
param2 <- scan(file="stdin", what=integer(0), n=1);
param3 <- scan(file="stdin", what=integer(0), n=1);
```

Of course, this dosn't work and I get the following output when i run the R script:

```
Read 1 item
Read 0 items
Read 0 items
Error in matrix(scan(file = "stdin", n = a_rows * a_cols), a_rows, a_cols,  :
  invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA)
Execution halted
```

In fact, if I try to read just the first two values:

```
a_rows <- scan(file="stdin", what=integer(0), n=1);
a_cols <- scan(file="stdin", what=integer(0), n=1);
```

I get the following ouput:

```
Read 1 item
Read 0 items
```

Does anyone have a good solution for this problem? I have been trying to find more information about the `scan` function but can't find anything about why I get this behavior.

**EDIT 1**
I'm running R version 3.1.0

```
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) -- "Spring Dance"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

**EDIT 2**
I have found a solution, the R code is as follows:

```
sin <- file("stdin");
open(sin);

a_rows <- scan(sin, what=integer(0), n=1);
a_cols <- scan(sin, what=integer(0), n=1);
A <- matrix(scan(sin, n = a_rows*a_cols), a_rows, a_cols, byrow = TRUE)

b_rows <- scan(sin, what=integer(0), n=1);
b_cols <- scan(sin, what=integer(0), n=1);
B <- matrix(scan(sin, n = b_rows*b_cols), b_rows, b_cols, byrow = TRUE)

param1 <- scan(sin, what=integer(0), n=1);
param2 <- scan(sin, what=integer(0), n=1);
param3 <- scan(sin, what=integer(0), n=1);
```

Why I have to open `stdin`, I don't know.

Answer (score -1):

I made three minor changes to your code and then it works:

1. Use `nlines=...` instead of `n=...`
2. Use `file=stdin()` instead of `file="stdin"`
3. Use `what=integer()` instead of `what=integer(0)`

Note: I have a suspicion that only `nlines=...` is important here.  The other changes are possibly not necessary.

Try this:

```
a_rows <- scan(file=stdin(), what=integer(), nlines=1);
a_cols <- scan(file=stdin(), what=integer(), nlines=1);
A <- matrix(scan(file=stdin(), nlines = a_rows), a_rows, a_cols, byrow = TRUE)
print(A)
```

Then I source the file:

```
> source('~/.active-rstudio-document')
1: 2
Read 1 item
1: 3
Read 1 item
1: 1
2: 2
Read 2 items
> source('~/.active-rstudio-document')
1: 2
Read 1 item
1: 3
Read 1 item
1: 1 2 3
4: 4 5 6
Read 6 items
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried using your code to read a matrix, but I get the following error: `Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  scan() expected 'an integer', got 'a_cols'`. If I change `file=stdin()` to `file="stdin"` I get the same error as in my original post. Worth mentioning is that I'm running: `R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) -- "Spring Dance"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)`